# Using $map in aggregate $group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to analyze some mongo db collections. What I need to extract the names and values of a collection.

Heres's how far I got:

```js
db.collection(coll.name)
  .aggregate([
    { $project: { arrayofkeyvalue: { $objectToArray: '$$ROOT' } } },
    { $unwind: '$arrayofkeyvalue' },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        allkeys: { $addToSet: '$arrayofkeyvalue.k' },
      },
    },
  ])
  .toArray();
```

This works quite nicely. I get all the keys. However I'd like to get the values too.

So, I thought "piece o' cake" and replaced the `allkeys` section with the `allkeysandvalues` section, which is supposed to create a map with key and value pairs.

Like this:

```js
db.collection(coll.name)
  .aggregate([
    { $project: { arrayofkeyvalue: { $objectToArray: '$$ROOT' } } },
    { $unwind: '$arrayofkeyvalue' },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        allkeysandvalues: {
          $map: {
            input: '$arrayofkeyvalue',
            as: 'kv',
            in: {
              k: '$$kv.k',
              v: '$$kv.v',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ])
  .toArray();
```

But that's not working. I get the error message

```
MongoError: unknown group operator '$map'
```

Does anyone know hot to solve this?

Comment: Can you add the https://mongoplayground.net/ link with sample data, you can't use $map within $group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage requires **accumulator expression** so you have to use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) instead of `$map`:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        allkeysandvalues: {
            $push: "$arrayofkeyvalue"
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        allkeysandvalues: {
            $push: {
                k: "$arrayofkeyvalue.k",
                v: "$arrayofkeyvalue.v"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which returns the same result.

Please note that `arrayofkeyvalue` is an object since you run `$unwind` prior to `$group`

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NkqwbAidG9a)

Answer (score 3):

> *MongoError: unknown group operator '$map'*

You can not use `$map` operator in `$group` stage directly in root level,

you can try adding one more group stage,

- `$group` by k (key) and get the first v (value)
- `$group` by null and construct the array of key-value pair
- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value pair array to object

```
db.collection(coll.name).aggregate([
  { $project: { arrayofkeyvalue: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
  { $unwind: "$arrayofkeyvalue" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$arrayofkeyvalue.k",
      value: { $first: "$arrayofkeyvalue.v" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      allkeysandvalues: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$value" } }
    }
  },
  { $project: { allkeysandvalues: { $arrayToObject: "$allkeysandvalues" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6pFDc8ABvnx)

Comment: Both answers were similar and correct. I had to choose one as the correct answer and chose the one, which came in faster. I am still grateful for your concise explanation. Thanks!